# Have issues in a SQLite helper class

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new in SQLite database. I currently created a database but I have two errors in my helper class inside the constructor for the `DATABASE_NAME` constant and the `DATABASE_VERSION`constant.
The error says:Cannot reference `PetDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME` before supertype constructor has been called.
I have the same error for `DATABASE_VERSION` constant.
PetDbHelper.java:

```
public class PetDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";
    private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public PetDbHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
       String SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE = "CRAETE TABLE" + PET_ENTRY.TABLE_NAME + "(" + PET_ENTRY._ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + PET_ENTRY.NAME + "TEXT NOT NULL," + PET_ENTRY.BREED + "TEXT," + PET_ENTRY.GENDER + "INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + PET_ENTRY.WEIGHT + "INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Comment: make static DATABASE_NAME,DATABASE_VERSION

Comment: I realised that my answer about calling `super` methods do not apply to this question, but you will need to call `super.onCreate(sqLiteDatabase)` and `super.onUpgrade(sqliteDatabase, i, i1);` to prevent a different  crash.

Comment: Ok,thanks @MichaelDodd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This variable cannot be referenced until the parent constructor function is initialized. When you add this variable to the `static` modifier, no more errors are reported .

**Change**

```
private final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";
private final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

**to**

```
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
```

Comment: Because you error is `Cannot reference PetDbHelper.DATABASE_NAME before supertype constructor has been called` .

Comment: And it was associated with the initialization sequence of Java .